# Can't find file index.ios.js in root directory react-native app

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

New to **react-native** & I'm trying to launch the default app but I'm getting the following error.

> error: bundling failed: "Cannot find entry file index.ios.js in any of
>   the roots:

Tried doing `react-native start --reset-cache` but no luck. also been searching GitHub forums but no luck. thanks for all the help. currently on version `0.49`. please help

Comment: note to self found this & worked (thank the lord) https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14246

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you kill the package manager completely, then try running these in your projects root directory:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
react-native run-ios
```

If you use watchman, this is an alternative set of steps beforehand that seems to work with a lot of people:

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
npm start -- --reset-cache
react-native run-ios
```